# In Matlab read a specific column of data in a text file

Tags: matlab

I have a text file that, when opened in excel, contains columns of data.

I want to use `textread` in matlab to read a specific column of data.

So, if it were an excel file, I could do:

```
Data = 'My_data_file.xlsx'; 
Column_C = xlsread(Data,'C:C');
```

But how do I do this with a text file?

Thanks!

Comment: `textscan` might do what you want: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html

Comment: if your columns are tab sperated you can check out this [link](http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91340-read-in-only-certain-columns-of-big-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to know the format of your file. If you have a file that looks like this :

`Name,Price,Volume`

`Sally,120,4.8`

`John,135,35.49324`

You could use the following code :

`[~,~,C]=textread('file.txt',%s,%f,%f);`

You will insert a `~` to suppress output of certain columns.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but you can go through--

```
help textread;
help csvwrite;
```

Once you get csv from txt, by

```
[num, txt, all] = xlsread('My_data_file.csv');
```

you can get everything in`all`.
How to get the column, you know well.